# Determining $dA$ in general

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I understand how to change coordinates and if I have $dx$ etc then I can find $du$ etc and visa-versa but I don't understand how to compute the surface differential in general.  I was asked to show that if $S$ is the surface obtained by rotating a curve $y=f(x)$ for $x\in [a,b]$ through an angle of $2\pi$ where $f(x)\ge 0$ and $f'$ is continuous then $S$ has a parameteric  representation given by $r(x,\theta)=(x,f(x)\cos(\theta),f(x)\sin(\theta))$ for $x\in [a,b]$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ and that the surface area of $S$ is given by 
$$A(S)= 2\pi \int_a^b f(x)\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$$

and in general if a smooth parametric surface is described by 
$$r(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)) \quad (u,v)\in D$$
then

$$A(S) = \iint_D |r_u \times r_v | dA$$

I've managed to show the parametric representation is indeed what is given (simply fix $x$ then you get a circle in the $yz$ plane and so you use the appropriate equation), then I showed in the rather routine way that 
$$|r_x \times r_\theta | = f(x)\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}$$

so I have that 
$$A(S)=\iint_D f(x)\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2} dA$$

but I don't know how to finish this.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's just $$A= \int_D \| r_u \times r_v \| du dv$$
It is $dA = \| r_u \times r_v \| du dv$, but that's just another way of writing the same thing as before.

Comment: Geometrically the cross product is the area of the figure generated by $r_u$ and $r_v$ so how do we tie these all together..... what's the intuition?

Comment: Yes, it is the area of the parallelogram enclosed by the two tangent vectors in a point. So what you're doing is calculate the area $dA$ of the "infinitesimal" parallelogram at every point and then sum over all of them through integration. That's the intuitive idea behind the formula. That's the same thing you do for curves length when you approximate them by polygonals which segment are shorter and shorter (up to "becoming infinitesimal"), but here you'got to calculate areas, so you're doing it with a lot of parallelograms and not segments.

Comment: Yeah but it seems like $dudv$ would almost be the area of a parallelogram too?  If we sweep $u$ an infinitesimal amount we get $du$ and when we do it for $v$ we get $dv$.  Seems like this is another parallelogram... guess I'm not understanding the $dudv$ part.

Comment: There comes the "infinitesimal part". The norm part is effectively the area of the parallelogram between the tangent vectors, which is a thing that has an extension, so it's not "infinitesimal". You can think of that like you're calculating the area of the parallellogram but with infinitesimal sides $du$ and $dv$. Of course, this is all just heuristics and formally $dudv$ it's just a notation in the integral (well, unless you want to summon 2-forms to give a precise mathematical meaning to $dudv$ through differential forms, but that's widely unnecessary here)

Comment: I'm familiar with differential forms.  I'm interested in hearing the explanation.  I've just been reviewing the basics for the math GRE, but I'm all ears.

Comment: Well, it's not something you can really resume in a comment :P If you're interested, you should look up for integration over Riemannian manifolds. Though, as I've anticipated, that give a mathematical (formal) meaning to $du$, which would otherwise be just a symbol in the integral.
But I'm afraid that's not what you're looking for. If you want to know the intuitive meaning behind is just what I told you. The idea behind the integral is always the same: you approximate better and better linearly by taking smaller portions of what you're integrating on (so it's segments for curves and...

Comment: ... it's portions of planes for surfaces), until the get so small they have no extension at all ("infinitesimal") and then you sum over. This is the basic idea and, in fact, you may define superficial or curvilinear integrals in the same way as you defined the ordinary Riemann integral: as the sup of finite sums over "partitions". For curves you take sum of polygonals lengths, for surfaces you take sum of areas of linear splines over a grid on the surface.